# Limit selection on Radio Button in Custom SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, splistitem

In SharePoint List, I have create Check boxes with three option in Choice Column.

Now, How to disable two options when one is selected in **new form**?

I tried by using this [Link](http://spjsblog.com/2009/12/31/limit-number-of-allowed-selections-in-checkboxes-choice/), but no use.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Radio Buttons field to instead of Checkboxes field.

If you still want to use Checkboxes, we can add the following code to script editor web part(2013/online) or Content Editor Web part(2010/2013/Online) in new form page to achieve it. **Note**: Modify the field column name in the code below.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    var columnName="Checkboxes";
    if($(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+columnName+"')").closest("tr").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length>1){
        alert("Only 1 selection allowed.");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried this, but not working

Comment: I modify the code above, don't forget modify the "columnName" in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/LimitSelectionsInCheckboxes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
initLimitSelections('YourFieldInternalName',1,'Only 1 selections allowed.');
</script>
```

> Code in LimitSelectionsInCheckboxes.js

```
var multiChoiceFields = init_multiChoiceFields();

function initLimitSelections(FieldInternalName,allowedSelections,errorText){
    if(typeof errorText === "undefined" || errorText === ""){
        errorText = "You can only select " + allowedSelections + " options.";
    }
    $(multiChoiceFields[FieldInternalName]).find("input").click(function(){
        limitSelections($(this),FieldInternalName,allowedSelections,errorText);
    });
}

function limitSelections(currOpt,fin,n,errText){
    var f = $(multiChoiceFields[fin]), c, chk;
    $("#customMultiSelectValidation").remove();
    c = f.find("input:checked").length;
    // If allowedSelections = 1 move selection
    if(n === 1){
        chk = currOpt.prop("checked");
        f.find("input:checked").each(function(){
            $(this).prop("checked",false);
        });
        currOpt.prop("checked",chk);
    }else{
        // Uncheck current selection and give user a visual feedback on number of allowed selections
        if(c > n){
            currOpt.prop("checked",false);
            f.find("td[class^='ms-formbody']").append("<div id='customMultiSelectValidation' class='ms-formvalidation'>" + errText + "</div>");
            $("#customMultiSelectValidation").fadeOut(4000)
        }
    }
}

function init_multiChoiceFields(){
    var res = {}, myMatch, disp, fin, type;
    $("td[class^='ms-formbody']").each(function(){
    myMatch = $(this).html().match(/FieldName="(.+)"\s+FieldInternalName="(.+)"\s+FieldType="(.+)"\s+/);    
        if(myMatch!=null){
            // Display name
            disp = myMatch[1];
            // FieldInternalName
            fin = myMatch[2];
            // FieldType
            type = myMatch[3];
            if(type!=='SPFieldMultiChoice'){
                return;
            }       
            // Build object
            res[fin] = this.parentNode;
            $(res[fin]).attr('FieldDispName',disp);
            $(res[fin]).attr('FieldType',type);
        }       
    });
    return res;
}
```

[Reference](http://spjsblog.com/2009/12/31/limit-number-of-allowed-selections-in-checkboxes-choice/)

Comment: http://spjsblog.com/2009/12/31/limit-number-of-allowed-selections-in-checkboxes-choice/ ....... I already gone through this link....